# NSIS compile-time command to calculate txt file and set result as global variable

Tags: nsis

I am a NSIS beginner and I need some help. I have a txt file which contains many rows of numbers. I want to use a compile-time command (such as !system or other) to read each line of numbers, add them together, and convert the sum into a global variable that can be used in the script. Can anyone suggest a good method to achieve this? Thank you very much in advance!

I wrote

**`!system 'for /f "tokens=1" %a in (filesize.txt) do set /a sum+=%a'`**

which ran successfully and I can see from the compile log that the result has been calculated. How can I convert the calculated result from the command line output to a variable that can be used globally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must redirect stdout to a file you can `!include`:

```
!tempfile STDOUT
!system 'echo StrCpy $0 1234 >> "${STDOUT}"'
!include "${STDOUT}"
!delfile "${STDOUT}"
!undef STDOUT
```

If the command is complex you might have to make a batch file:

```
!tempfile BAT
!appendfile "${BAT}.bat" 'echo foo >> %1$\n'
!appendfile "${BAT}.bat" 'dir bar >> %1$\n'
!tempfile STDOUT
!system '"${BAT}.bat" "${STDOUT}"'
!delfile "${BAT}.bat"
!undef BAT
!include "${STDOUT}"
!delfile "${STDOUT}"
!undef STDOUT
```